# Asking About Work/Life Balance and On-Call In an Interview

Tags: interviewing, work-life-balance

Work/Life Balance and On-Call requirements are two things that I want to know about before accepting a job offer. I'm afraid that when asking about these in an interview that it's perceived that I don't want to work or do a good job. That's not the case at all. I just don't want to be working an average of 12 hours a day and sitting by the phone all weekend. Is it wrong to ask about these things in an interview and is there a way to ask without coming off as just not wanting to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I ask about work/life balance during an Interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/how-should-i-ask-about-work-life-balance-during-an-interview)

Comment: Ask to interview your future co-workers. There is the official policy and then there is the policy actually applied in practice. And ask questions that start with "Your first year, did you blah blah?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're worried about misperceptions from asking a question, there is a simple solution - accompany the question with your motives for asking. The benefits of the answer you're looking for.

If possible, also mention the benefits to the company. This further emphasises that you're asking for the right reasons, and lets them know you're aware of these and they matter to you. In this case, it might be that a reasonable work schedule and work/life balance will let you be productive sustainably.

Having the discussion on the specific terms you most care about is the best way both to ensure they understand your position, and you understand theirs, and hence whether it'll likely be a good fit.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with asking about these things and no company you want to work for will see them as a bad sign. Actually, these are pretty standard things to talk about in an interview. Companies that think of those questions as a red flag are the ones you should avoid.